# Image of divisors under étale cover

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be an étale cover of degree $d$ between two smooth projective varieties.

If $V\subset X$ is an effective reduced and irreducible divisor, does $f$ restrict to an isomorphism $V\simeq f(V)$ ? I am interested in the case of a double cover (i.e. $d=2$), but I expect the answer is general.

**Added**: Let $\iota$ denote the sheet-interchange involution induced on $X$. I expect the answer to the above question to be NO whenever $\iota(V)=V$, of course. But can this actually happen (does it always happen)? Secondly, is the answer automatically YES whenever $\iota(V)\neq V$?

Comment: Take $\dim X=\dim Y=2$ and let $p\neq q\in X$ such that $f(p)=f(q)$. By Bertini, you can find a smooth irreducible curve $V$ in $X$ passing through $p,q$. Clearly, $V$ is not isomorphic to $f(V)$.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, could you explain me in more details how you'd use Bertini? It seems to me that you would take a linear system where $p,q$ would be base-points.

Comment: Please look up an appropriate text, Bertini is technical and messy to explain in a few sentences.

Comment: @Mohan. What I can imagine is to fix a projective embedding of $X$, take $p,q$ and consider the system of hyperplane sections containing $p,q$. But this system has $p,q$ as base-points, so the general element might still be singular at $p,q$. Please, would you mind expanding your comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is a sketch. Let $f:X\to Y$ be an etale cover of smooth projective surfaces of degree 2 (higher degrees will work too). Let $p\neq q$ be points in $X$ such that $f(p)=f(q)$. I claim that there is an irreducible curve $C$ passing through $p,q$ and then clearly $f:C\to f(C)$ is not injective.

For this, I use a lovely argument by C. P. Ramanujam (see his collected works, if you have access). Let $g:Z\to X$ be the blow up of $p,q$, then $Z$ is projective and thus a general hyperplane section $H\subset Z$ is irreducible, by the usual Bertini. But, being a hyperplane, $H$ has to meet both the exceptional curves over $p,q$ and thus $g(H)=C$ is an irreducible curve on $X$ passing through both $p,q$.

Comment: Dear Mohan. Thanks for your answer. This is indeed a lovely argument. What is the precise reference of these collected works?